# Solving equation involving cdf of standard normal distribution

Tags: polynomials, normal-distribution, maple

How do I solve the following equation for $n$ using Maple:
$$2\Phi\left(\frac{0.01}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi^{5}-2\pi^{4}}{2\pi^{2}n}}}\right)-1=0.95,$$
where $\Phi(x)$ denotes the cdf of a standard normal distribution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `solve(` your equation here `, n)` with $\Phi(\dots)$ replaced with `PDF(RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)), ...)` some time after the line `with(Statistics)`?

Comment: Problem is I am not very familiar with Maple, so no I have not. So I've just written everything explicitly, and I can't seem to make it work. I know that the answer is $n\approx 216000$.

Comment: At least, simplify the powers of $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, I should do that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maple the inverse of the CDF is implemented as the `Quantile` command from the `Statistics` package. For example,

```
restart; with(Statistics):
Quantile( RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)), 0.975 );

             1.95996398453944
```

If you prefer you can skip several easy steps and directly write down the reformulated equation,

```
restart;
with(Statistics):
X:=RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)):
0.01/sqrt((Pi^5-2*Pi^4)/(2*Pi^2*n))=Quantile(X,0.975):
fsolve(%);

                216409.8864
```

Or it can all be done starting from the originally supplied equation, with no mental rearrangement of the equations required.

```
restart;
with(Statistics):
X:=RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)):
eq:=2*Phi(0.01/sqrt((Pi^5-2*Pi^4)/(2*Pi^2*n)))-1=0.95:
new1:=isolate(eq,indets(eq,specfunc(anything,Phi))[1]):
new2:=eval(map((Phi@@(-1)),new1),
           (Phi@@(-1))=(p->Quantile(X,p))):
fsolve(new2,{n});

             {n = 216409.8864}
```

I'll break down some of those steps, for explanation.

```
restart;
with(Statistics):
X:=RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)):
```

I'll start with the `eq` as given.

```
eq:=2*Phi(0.01/sqrt((Pi^5-2*Pi^4)/(2*Pi^2*n)))-1=0.95:
```

The only function call to `Phi`, in `eq`,

```
indets(eq,specfunc(anything,Phi))[1];

    Phi(.1e-1*2^(1/2)*Pi/(1/n*(Pi^5-2*Pi^4))^(1/2))
```

Isolating `eq` for that call to `Phi`

```
new1 := isolate(eq,indets(eq,specfunc(anything,Phi))[1]);

    Phi(.1e-1*2^(1/2)*Pi/(1/n*(Pi^5-2*Pi^4))^(1/2))
    = .9750000000
```

Applying the inverse of `Phi` to both side of that new equation.

```
map((Phi@@(-1)),new1);

    .1e-1*2^(1/2)*Pi/(1/n*(Pi^5-2*Pi^4))^(1/2)
    = (Phi@@(-1))(.9750000000)
```

The same as previous, but following up by replacing the generic inverse `Phi` call with a call to `Quantile` (using R.V. `X`).

```
new2:=eval(map((Phi@@(-1)),new1),
           (Phi@@(-1))=(p->Quantile(X,p)));

    .1e-1*2^(1/2)*Pi/(1/n*(Pi^5-2*Pi^4))^(1/2)
    = 1.95996398453944232
```

Solving that, numerically,

```
fsolve(new2,{n});

           {n = 216409.8864}
```

or, if preferred,

```
fsolve(new2,n);

               216409.8864
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working Maple at home, so based on [Distributions:Normal](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics%2FDistributions%2FNormal) and [solve](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=solve), try

```
with(Statistics)
solve( 2 * PDF( RandomVariable(Normal(0,1)), 0.01/sqrt((Pi^5 - 2 Pi^4)/(2*Pi^2 * n)) ) - 1 = 0.95, n)
```

Now maybe Maple's `solve` doesn't know how or recognize that it can apply the inverse CDF, [norminv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html), so we have to do that manually...

```
with(Statistics)
first = solve( 2*phi - 1 = 0.95, phi)
solve( 0.01/sqrt((Pi^5 - 2 Pi^4)/(2*Pi^2 * n)) = norminv(first), n)
```

Again, I don't have Maple handy, so these may require a few rounds of tweaking to get right, so feel free to comment with progress or results.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit solution is

$$n=10000\dfrac{\pi^{3}-2\pi^{2}}{2}\left(\Phi^{-1}(0.975)\right)^2\approx216400$$

using $\Phi^{-1}(0.975)=1.9600$ from a table.